# how to avoid to Specify a username and password for datasource in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS as a part of my project for displaying reports. It accesses data from SQL data source.Here my problem is that each time I view my report on the browser, it asks me like this

"Specify a user name and password for data source"

I need to avoid this prompt while seeing my report on the browser. Kindly suggest what should i do to get rid of my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this can be fixed..  You should

- Go into your DataSource properties
- Select Credentials
- Select "Use this user name and password"
- Enter the credentials that you want to use with the report
- Save the report (or DataSource if it's a shared DataSource)

The default option for data sources is to prompt for credentials, so this is expected behavior unless you change it.

Comment: One tip is especially with multiple subreports, somewhere down the change an **embedded** Data Source or pointing to a different shared Data Source, if any one of the children has Prompt for Credentials set, it will cause the prompt to appear.  So you have to double check all subreports and their data sources.