# SSRS not remembering set passwords when report is re--opened

Tags: reporting-services

I have goggled aroung and have no come across the same issue I'm experiencing. Basically I'm using report  builder 3.0 with a sql 2014 database. When I create the report, I'm saving the username and password within the report. Its a generic username that has access to the database.

At this stage everything works, problem is that if I close report builder and re-open the report it will ask me to enter the username and password again.If I enter and save it will run, but if I reopen again the passwords are lost.

Any advice or it this a know issue?
I'm following the steps listed here [how to avoid to Specify a username and password for datasource in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422892/how-to-avoid-to-specify-a-username-and-password-for-datasource-in-ssrs)

This is how I'm saving the details
[image]

Mark

Comment: just checked 'save my password' property at the time of creating/editing the Data source connection property

Comment: There is no "save my password option", see screeenshots I've added showing how I'm saving it. Is the option somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is this

1. 1-Just Open the DataSource on the General Tab, Set up your
   ConnectionString with your username and password and the database
   name.
2. In the Credentials Tab, just Check "Do not use credentials.
3. Save your report and open it again and run it.

[1-General Tab inside the Data Source Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snqpX.png)
[2-Credentials inside the Data Source Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEMfR.jpg)